# Upload picture with redactorJS, it isn't displayed in editor, though it is successfully uploads to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redactor.js

I've successfully installed `redactorJS`, using gem `redactor-rails` into my Rails project. I have included `js` and `css` files to assets. Then, I ran `rails generate redactor:install` and `rails generate redactor:config`. It has created models, uploaders, route and migration. The second command created a `config.js` file:

```
window.init_redactor = function(){
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
  var params;
  if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
      params = csrf_param + "=" + encodeURIComponent(csrf_token);
  }
  $('.redactor').redactor({
        // You can specify, which ones plugins you need.
        // If you want to use plugins, you have add plugins to your
        // application.js and application.css files and uncomment the line below:
        // "plugins": ['fontsize', 'fontcolor', 'fontfamily', 'fullscreen', 'textdirection', 'clips'],
        imageUpload: "/redactor_rails/pictures?" + params,
        imageGetJson :"/redactor_rails/pictures",
        fileUpload: "/redactor_rails/documents?" + params,
        fileGetJson: "/redactor_rails/documents",
        path: "/assets/redactor-rails",
        css :"style.css",
      });
};

$(document).on( 'ready page:load', window.init_redactor );
```

The problem is that the images are uploaded, but they are not displayed in the editor, and also the `src` attribute of image tags are blank. Am I missing something, or, maybe, I'm doing everything in a wrong way? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

For some reason, when I go to this route: `redactor_rails/pictures` so I could get `json` of images, I get this error:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'redactor_assets.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `redactor_assets`.* FROM `redactor_assets` WHERE `redactor_assets`.`type` IN ('RedactorRails::Picture') AND `redactor_assets`.`user_id` = 20

Can't find why is it going to retrieve `redactor_assets.user_id`.

Comment: hi, do you have a migration for this? did you migrate your db? are you using the deprecated version of `redactor` for `rails 3.2` or `redactor2_rails`? what version of rails are you using?

Comment: All migrations are passed, and I use rails 5.0.5, gem `redactor-rails`

Comment: `redactor-rails` is deprecated and only used for `rails 3.2`, `redactor2_rails` is only available for `rails 3x - 4` https://github.com/Redactor2/redactor2_rails

Comment: Indeed, the issue was in the deprecated gem. Installing `redactor2_rails` solved the issue.